# Maven source:jar task results in warnings

Tags: java, windows, maven, jenkins

We are using Maven 3.0.5 as build tool for our projects and have windows only clients and servers. Building the software localy gives a clean maven output without any warnings. Running the same build on our ci server Jenkins we get this warning:

```
[WARNING] Failed to getClass for org.apache.maven.plugin.source.SourceJarMojo
```

We get the warning as soon, as we include the `source:jar` goal in our build.

mvn cmd: `-e clean source:jar`.

Does anyone know what this means, and how to get rid of it?
I can not find any hint how to fix it, but searching google a lot of Jenkins build logs contain this warning.

**[EDIT] Configuration**

- Windows Server 2008 R2 (locale: de)
- Maven 3.0.5
- maven-source-plugin: 2.2.1

I also tried to upgrade the maven-source-plugin to the latest version `2.4` with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Maven plugin for Jenkins installed? 
The configuration for using maven on Jenkins is:
Maven installed on your system.
M3_HOME configured in the path
Maven plugin installed on jenkins

Comment: yes, i have both maven and the plugin for jenkins. But i have multiple maven versions on my jenkins, so I have not set any enviroment variable, but configured the right paths inside jenkins config.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem.I went to my IE setting->LAN Settings.Then copied the Address as host and port as the port and it worked. Following is the snapshot of the proxies tag in the Settings.xml that I changed.

```
  <proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <!--username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>proxypass</password-->
  <host>webtitan</host>
  <port>8881</port>
  <!--nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts-->
  </proxy>
```

Comment: tried it, but it doesn't change anything. I changed the settings.xml and rerun the build.